# Numerical Column Not displaying numerical correctly in DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a df such as below **( 3 rows for example )**

```
ID | Dollar_Value
C       45.32
E       5.21
V       121.32
```

When I view the df in my notebook such as df:
It shows the Dollar_value as

```
ID | Dollar_Value
C       8.493000e+01
E       2.720000e+01
V       1.720000e+01
```

Instead of the regular format, but when I try to filter the df for specific ID, it shows the values as they are supposed to be ( 82.23 or 2.45)

```
df[df['ID'] == 'E']

 ID | Dollar_Value
 E       45.32
```

is there something I have to do formatting wise? So the df itself can display the value column as its supposed to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try run this code before print , since you columns may have big number or very small number.(Check with `df.describe()`)

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the code in the lambda do? (  '%.3f' % x)

Comment: @Chris90 set the digit back